# Remoting SecurityException from dll

Tags: c#, dll, nunit, remoting

I need to test old legacy remoting service.
The code comes with ready to use client side which means I have an object that takes care of all the channeling implementation.

When connecting to this client from executable - everything is good and works great, but when trying to do the same operation using dll (nunit is the test framework) SecurityException is thrown whenever I'm trying to query the service.

Why there is difference using dll code over executable?

This is the error message:

> Type System.Runtime.Remoting.ObjRef and the types derived from it
>   (such as System.Runtime.Remoting.ObjRef) are not permitted to be
>   deserialized at this security level.

needless to say I have no access to the server side code, but it is .Net 4.5 (although remoting) and the test code is also .Net 4.5, and I must mention I run the code on the same machine

This is the code generates the  client side channel

```
 public class RemoteClient
    {
        public static RemoteClient GenerateClient()
        {
            SetupHttpChannelAndBuildUrl();

            cm_remote obj = null;
            try
            {
                obj = (cm_remote) Activator.GetObject(typeof (cm_remote_base), url);
                obj.DoSomething();
                return obj;
            }
            catch (Exception e)

            {
            ...
            }
        }

        private static SetupHttpChannelAndBuildUrl()
        {
        ...
        }

        public void DoSomethig()
        {
        ...
        }
    }
```

and this is the both dll and exe code triggering the functionality:

```
public RemoteClient GetRemoteClient()
    {
        return RemoteClient.GenerateClient();
    }
```

from exe it returns instance of RemoteClient, from dll returns null

Comment: Could you post your code in `SetupHttpChannelAndBuildUrl` and the stacktrace of the exception please?

Comment: @NeilBlackburn The problem related to nUnit 2.6.2 which is been used. I would publish answer as I get the full picture.

Comment: @SaturnTechnologies Did you determine if that was the issue? I believe it may be because I'm having the same issue. . .

Comment: It's been awhile, but as far as I remember nunit does not support remoting. As far as I remember moving to xUnit solved this issue. In general I would recommend moving to xUnit as it supports more .Net internal technologies (from my experience) or examine using nunit 3.0 (currently in Beta)